# HTML small padding issue I can't quite figure out

Tags: html-email

I've created an email newsletter.

It displays **perfectly** across all email clients, including Outlook 2000 and Outlook 2003.

Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 are the only one that have an issue. This is the issue. What can I do to fix it? :(

Comment: I see the same error on FF16

Comment: @Giovanni Sferro: I use FF 16.02 and don't see the issue? If you know what's causing it please advise? Thank you. This is mainly for email clients as well.

Comment: The issue is a mis-alignment of the images, right? I don't know because to me it's only a matter of wrong margins. Also same error on Opera 12.10.

Comment: @Giovanni Sferro: Yep, see that right side under the plane? All that should be moved down to cover the white space. But, if I move it down it will put everything out of proportion for other email clients.

Comment: It's only a guess, but it could be something related to default margins applyied by browsers. Can you use css? doctype? Usually using a reset-css and an appropriate doctype you should cut down most of the inter-browsers differences. Also, consider the idea to use divs instead of tables, it's a bad design.

Comment: It's for an email newsletter, strictly table layout rather than div's and also using inline css...?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the left column shorter by chopping off some of the bottom red area.

Comment: Thank you - but the strange this is that it displays perfectly in all other email clients, just not these 3 versions of Outlook. If I chop a bit, won't it mess up again for the alternate versions of Outlook that it currently works on?

Comment: You shouldn't do no, but you'll need to test it to confirm. And if it does screw up in the other email clients, but fixes it in the 3 versions of Outlook it's currently broken in, you'll just have to make the call of which versions to 'support'. What versions are the majority of your user base on? Sometime with HTML emails, there is just no way to make things work perfectly in every client. It's just the way it is. I very often get emails from very well known/big companies that are misaligned or otherwise messed up in some way...